# upscaling and comparing

Tags: java, casting, floating-point

I can't seem to find the reason why the below code is breaking:

From my perspective what happens is that the integer lbnd is decreased

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        methode1();
    }
    static void methode1() {
        int ubnd = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int lbnd = ubnd;

        while ((float)lbnd == (float)ubnd) {
            --lbnd;
        }   
        System.out.println((++lbnd) + ".." + ubnd);
    }
}
```

the thing is that this loop should be an infinite loop from what I see, however it breaks after 64 loops because the ints changed in value. The outcome is:

2147483584..2147483647

but it should be an infinite loop with:

2147483647..2147483647

Comment: sorry I have added the problem*

Comment: what do you mean by `upscaling`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that **a float does not have sufficient precision to store all 32 bits of an integer precisely**. So for an integer of high magnitude, (float) i and (float) (i-1) are identical for the purposes of a float comparison.

(Incidentally, when comparing an int and a float, it will be treated as a float comparison. So to illustrate an additional gotcha, you don't even need the cast to float on one side of your == comparison.)

Comment: ah alright I understand that now, however why does the program not break at 2147483640. when rounded this would give 2.14748364 instead of 2.14748365

Comment: Remember that the computer doesn't "think" in decimal, though. The actual rounding error that occurs is in the underlying binary.

Answer (score 0):

To verify Neil Coffey's excellent answer you can look at the output of your code with additional output:

```
   while ((float)lbnd == (float)ubnd) {
        System.out.println(
                "Lower Int " + lbnd 
                + " Lower Float " + (float)lbnd 
                + " .. Upper Int " + ubnd
                + " Upper Float "+ (float)ubnd);
        --lbnd;
    }   
    System.out.println((++lbnd) + ".." + ubnd);
```

Comment: I think printing the exact integer values of lbnd and ubnd is even more interesting. You can see lbnd reduce by one on each iteration, until it is small enough for its float conversion to change.

Answer (score 0):

For large ints, a block of several ints all round to the same float, so for the first few iterations the float conversion of lbnd remains equal to the float conversion of ubnd.

After you do enough int subtractions from lbnd, it is small enough to map to the next lower float value, and the two float conversions become different, ending the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are decrementing and incrementing lbnd. This indicates a difference of one. One is only significant (in strictfp floating point) up to the number 16777217. If your vm has higher precision (non-strictfp) the number may be higher.